# Nodejs, mysql 'connection lost the server closed the connection'

Tags: mysql, node.js

I connected mysql to nodejs. After a certain period of time, you will get the error :

> **'Connection lost the server closed the connection'**.

I need your help.

An error has occurred and we added the function `handleDisconnect`. However, once a disconnect is resolved, the second error occurs again from `Connection lost the server closed the connection`.

I wonder why it should be only once and not the second one.

ps: The description may not be smooth using a translator.

This is part of the `app.js` file

```
// connection to databases
var mysql_dbc = require('./config/db_con')();
var connection = mysql_dbc.init();
mysql_dbc.test_open(connection);

// Added Code
handleDisconnect(connection);
function handleDisconnect(client) {

  client.on('error', function (error) {

    if (!error.fatal) return;

    if (error.code !== 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') throw err;

    console.error('> Re-connecting lost MySQL connection: ' + error.stack);

    mysql_dbc.test_open(connection);

  });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#server-disconnects) code to handle server disconnect:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var configuration = {
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "mysql",
  database: "blog"
};
var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {
  connection = mysql.createConnection(configuration);

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error when connecting to db:", err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000);
    }else{
        console.log("connection is successfull");
    }
  });
  connection.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("db error", err);
    if (err.code === "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST") {
      handleDisconnect();
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
}
handleDisconnect();
```

You may lose the connection to a MySQL server due to network problems,
 the server timing you out, the server being restarted, or crashing.
 All of these events are considered fatal errors.

Re-connecting a connection is done by establishing a new connection.
Once terminated, an existing connection object cannot be re-connected by design.

With Pool, disconnected connections will be removed from the pool freeing up space for a new connection to be created on the next getConnection call.

Comment: Thank you for your first response. I get an error in this part. Did you have a typo?

`if(err) {                                   sometimes).`

Comment: yes, sorry removed it. you can check it now. it sould work